# How to install a dependency in my local project in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, dependencies, java-ee-7

How can I install a dependency/library in my local project?

Because now I see that all my dependencies get installed to:

`C:\Users\yomac_000\.m2\repository`

With npm (a dependency/library installer like Maven but then for Node.js) I can do the following command to install a library to my project:

`npm install <library_name>`

And if I do:

`npm install -g <library_name>`

Then that will install the library in C:\somepath.

Answer (score 1):

The `.m2/repository` folder is called local repository. All dependencies are downloaded into this folder, so your projects can share them. If you want to "install" dependencies to your project, create pom.xml and set appropriate packaging type (for example, war for web application) and scope. That way the dependencies will be accessible in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

If you really need to change the path of your local repository, you can do it by editing maven configuration. See [this page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html) to get info about maven configuration.

---

See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html for general info about `pom.xml` file.

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html for detailed info about dependency mechanism that maven uses. Available scopes are also described here.

Comment: If I change the path of my local repository with `<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo/</localRepository>`. Then `project A` and `project B` still install their libraries on the newly changed path.. So how can I manage that `project A` install his dependencies inside `project A`?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is this kind of an option. Maven doesn't work like this. It makes your projects share the dependencies. And then, when you build a project, it packs the dependencies together with the project. I. e. you don't need to care about local repository location, just define the dependencies in pom and maven will take care about the rest. See the links I have stated in the answer.

Comment: Yes I know, but what's going to happen if `project A` uses a library called `testLibrary 1.0` and `project B` uses a library called `testLibrary 2.0` ? I assume then that Maven is going to delete `testLibrary 1.0` and update it with  `testLibrary 2.0` . Which means that I can't run `project A` anymore..

Comment: In this case, you will have two versions of `testLibrary` downloaded in your local repository. Version 1.0 will be (after build) packed with `project A` and version 2.0 with `project B`. Maven supports versioning of dependencies.